# Oracle11g - Are Unique Constraints violations audited - logged on a table?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, unique-constraint

I would like to know if I insertion attempts violating a unique constraint on a table are available on an Oracle system table or not. If not your suggestions are welcome.
My system is Oracle 11g.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly :

- If you control the insertion then yes - you can use the `LOG ERRORS INTO` clause.
- If its being performed in sqlplus you can use the `set errorlogging on` clause.
- You could put an INSERT trigger on the table, but that would be pretty horrid.

Comment: Could you please elaborate the use of this clause? A trigger-free solution is much appreciated.

Comment: The easiest option there is google the docs - the trick is always knowing the technical term of what you are searching for.